# Enable TRIM on the windows partitions?

Tags: ssd, trim

Do I need to enable TRIM for the windows 8.1 partition on my dual boot ultrabook if I will be reading/writing to the windows partition while booted into Ubuntu? Also do I need to enable it for a shared NTFS partition that I have in which I store files that I want to access from within Windows and Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Linux doesn't support the TRIM operation on NTFS partitions, so you CAN'T enable it. (If it would support it, then yes, you should enable it.)